# TTL index on oplog or reducing the size of oplog?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I am using mongodb with elasticsearch for my application. Elasticsearch creates indexes by monitioring oplog collection. When both the applications are running constantly then any changes to the collections in mongodb are immediately indexed. The only problem I face is if for some reason I had to delete and recreate the index then it takes ages(2days) for the indexing to complete.

When I was looking at the size of my oplog by default it's capacity is 40gb and its holding around 60million transactions because of which creating a fresh index is taking a long time.
What would be the best way to optimize fresh index creation?

Is it to reduce the size of oplog so that it holds less number of transactions and still not affect my replication or is it possible to create a ttl index(which I failed to do on several attempts) on oplog.

I am using elasticsearch with mongodb using mongodb river https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/.

Any help to overcome the above mentioned issues is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Elastic Search Pro but your question:

> What would be the best way to optimize fresh index creation?

Does apply a little to all who use third party FTS techs with MongoDB.

The first thing to note is that if you have A LOT of records then there is no easy way around this unless you are prepared to lose some of them.

The oplog isn't really a good idea for this, you should probably seek out using a custom script using timers in the main collection to do this personally, or a change table giving you a single place to quickly query for new or updated records.

Unless you are filtering the oplog to get specific records, i.e. inserts, then you could be pulling out ALL oplog records including deletes, collection operations and even database operations. So you could try stripping out unneeded records from your oplog search, however, this then creates a new problem; the oplog has no indexes or index updating.

This means that if you start to read in a manner more appropiate you will actually use an unindexed query over these 60 million records. This will result in slow(er) performance.

The oplog having no index updating answers another one of your questions:

> is it possible to create a ttl index(which I failed to do on several attempts) on oplog.

Nope.

As for the other one of your questions:

> Is it to reduce the size of oplog so that it holds less number of transactions

Yes, but you will have a smaller recovery window of replication and not only that but you will lose records from your "fresh" index so only a part of your data is actually indexed. I am unsure, from your question, if this is a problem or not.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding the TTL. As far as the oplog size is considered I am testing for the optimal size so that I will not have problems with replication and indexing.

Comment: @dittu Good thing is to calculate how many days worth you have, that's how the oplog size should really be calced, from there you can decide how many days you really need

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the oplog for a single secondary member that no replica is synching from. Look up rs.syncFrom and "Change the Size of the Oplog" in the mongodb docs.